# List index out of range error (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am getting a list index out of range error.  I have tried looking at the code again and again but I am not getting anything as I do not know the syntax of  python and lists very well.

This is the relevant code:

```
    while True:
          final = "Triangle_x128_y128.bmp"
          imageSizeToServe = re.findall(r'\d+', final)
          imageSize= imageSizeToServe[0]
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python27\MyServer.py", line 25, in <module>
imageSize= imageSizeToServe[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: while True:
          final = "Triangle_x128_y128.bmp" 
          imageSizeToServe = re.findall(r'\d+', final) 
          imageSize= imageSizeToServe[0]

Comment: You can make an edit to your question :) Also, it looks as if you have an empty list...

Comment: If `[0]` raises an `IndexError`, then `imageSizeToServe` was empty at the time you queried it for index 0.

Comment: make sure that `imageSizeToServer` is not empty.

Comment: The code works for me as is which is odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexError: list index out of range` raised because `imageSizeToServe` is empty.

Check it before get zero index. Like:

```
if imageSizeToServe:
    imageSize = imageSizeToServe[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Make sure you had written the same code here and in your program. Anyway, you can check the emptiness of a list with

```
if imageSizeToServe:
```